# Another Internet Explorer problem... JQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Here is my spaggeti code

```
$("#table_exams tbody tr").click(function ()
{
    window.location.hash="#" +$(this).attr("exam_ID");
     window.location.href="/medilab/prototypes/exams/edit?examId=" + $(this).attr("exam_ID") +"&referer=" + referer;

   row_select(this);
});

$("#table_exams tbody tr td a").click(function ()
{

    window.location.hash="#" +$(this).parent().parent().attr("exam_ID");        
    var where="/medilab/prototypes/exams/edit?examId=" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("exam_ID") +"&referer=" + referer;
    window.open(where);
    row_select($(this).parent().parent());
    alert("propaganda");
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;

});
```

The problem is that when this function is triggered

```
$("#table_exams tbody tr td a").click(function ()
{
```

the other function is triggered also.... only in IE...
What can i do for this????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$("#table_exams tbody tr td a").click(function () {
```

Needs to be this:

```
$("#table_exams tbody tr td a").click(function (event) {
```

You're not passing the proper event into the function, I'd imagine you're getting an undefined on `event.stopPropagation();` in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the event into the function. In both functions, change `.click(function ()` to `.click(function (event)`

You can also add `alert(event.isPropagationStopped())` to debug further if required.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `event.stopPropagation();` should do the trick, see [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

```
$("#table_exams tbody tr td a").click(function (event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.location.hash="#" +$(this).parent().parent().attr("exam_ID");        
    var where="/medilab/prototypes/exams/edit?examId=" +     $(this).parent().parent().attr("exam_ID") +"&referer=" + referer;
    window.open(where);
    row_select($(this).parent().parent());
    alert("propaganda");
    return false;    
});
```